# Interesting XOR expression evaluation in javascript

Tags: javascript, order-of-execution

Tried out the expression `a ^= b ^= a ^= b` with `a` and `b` taking values `3` and `5` respectively. When executed in Javascript the answer is `a = 0` and `b = 5`, but when run in C the variables got reversed to `a = 5` and `b = 3`.

[image: Executed in browser]
[image: Executed in C playground]

Comment: Well, they’re two different languages, sooo… What would you have expected the “correct” result to be and why?

Comment: In C you get undefined behavior if you modify the same variable multiple times in an expression. JS defines the order of operations.

Answer (score 0):

In compound assignment operations, the value of the assignee is evaluated *once*.

This does not make a difference for simple expression like `x += y` and the result is the same as `x = x + y`, however it actually is `x = <current value of x> + y`. This it does matter in chained assignments. Compare the chained `x += y += x += y`

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 1;

x += y += x += y;

console.log(`x = ${x} y = ${y}`);
```

to breaking it down into the same steps

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 1;

x += y
y += x
x += y;

console.log(`x = ${x} y = ${y}`);
```

This shows the difference, where the the chained compound assignment the start is

```
x += <expression>
```

which gets resolved as

```
x = 1 + <expression>
//  ^ current value of x
```

Thus even more succinctly this can be demonstrated as

```js
let x = 1;

x += x = 7;

console.log(x); // 1 + 7 = 8
```

Thus the result of `a ^= b ^= a ^= b` is zero, since `b ^= a ^= b` returns the same value as `a` and XOR on the same value is always zero.

```
a = 3 dec = 011 bin;
b = 5 dec = 101 bin;

a ^= b ^= a ^= b

a = 011 bin ^ (b ^= a ^= b)
a = 011 bin ^ (b = (101 bin^ (a ^= b)))
a = 011 bin ^ (b = (101 bin ^ (a = (011 bin^ b))))

a = 011 bin ^ (b = (101 bin ^ (a = (011 bin ^ 101 bin))))
a = 011 bin ^ (b = (101 bin ^ (a = 110 bin)))
a = 011 bin ^ (b = (101 bin ^ 110 bin))
a = 011 bin ^ (b = 011 bin)
a = 011 bin ^ 011 bin
a = 000 bin
```